# Remove modules from libxml2

Tags: xml, libxml2, autoconf

I would like to compile `libxml2` with minimum modules. For instance, I do not need `xPath`.
I ran the command

```
./configure --with-xpath=off
```

but it does not work.
Of course after that I ran

```
make & make install.
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [autoconf documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#External-Software), you should use either

```
./configure --with-xpath=no
```

or

```
./configure --without-xpath
```